# Neo4J node_auto_indexing and relationship_auto_indexing

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I want to know, if the two settings node_auto_indexing and relationship_auto_indexing in the neo4j.properties concerning the ids of nodes and rels?

or creates neo4j automatically an index for the ids of the inserted nodes and rels?

Comment: Is the `id` you are talking about the node-id or a custom id of your own?

Comment: i am talking about the node-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you shouldn't add your ID to the auto index. There is no use for it, since you can already retrieve nodes by ID, without using auto index.

There are however occassions where the usual ID is not sufficient. For instance, when working with users, you may have a user id of some kind. You'd then store this in a property, and add that property to the auto index. This way, you can search by user id. Underlying, Neo4J matches your custom user ID, with the actual node id.

Important to keep in mind here is that per definition, auto index is not unique. You need to design your application in such a fashion that the property is in fact unique, if you're expecting a single node result.

Answer (score 1):

the auto index creates index for all properties defined at the `*_keys_indexable` line in the `neo4j.properties` file.

the index then bounds the node ID with the specific property value. thus, searching the index for the the property value will return the node.

since your question is a bit unclear to me, you might want to take a look at official docu:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html

Comment: ah okay, so it doesn't make sense to add e.g. "id" to "node_keys_indexable", right? because id is already an index

Comment: probably, yes. but i don't know your exact case so i can't tell you. could you please tell us what are you trying to do with your data?